# Return the minimum of single field grouping in wider query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a query:

```
select
    e.eid,
    e.event_time as contact_created,
    cs.name as initial_class,
    cn.create_time as lead_date
from bm_sets.event378 e
inner join bm_config.classes cs on cs.id = e.class_id and cs.cid=378 # and cs.name = 'Candidate'
left join bm_sets.conversion378 cn on cn.eid = e.eid and cn.create_time > e.event_time
where e.eid = 283818 
group by eid, contact_created, initial_class, lead_date
```

The results of this query look like this:

```
eid,    contact_created, initial_class, lead_date
283818  2015-03-07 09:43:42 Hot 
283818  2015-03-10 22:19:47 Candidate   
283818  2015-03-10 22:22:11 Candidate
```

I need to adjust this query so that only the first record is returned, the one with the min contact_created date. But since I'm using an aggregate function with other fields, I'm grouping by initial_class too so min is the min based on the combined groupings.

Our server seems to struggle whenever I use a subquery. So I tried using another join as a filter, something like:

```
inner join bm_sets.event378 e1 on e1.eid = e.eid and e1.event_time < e.event_time
```

But I know before running it that this won't work since the eid (user id) 283818 will still be returned and thus all associated data.

How can I restrict the results to only those records that correspond to the minimum of event_time?

I am using the where condition 283818 (my own user id for debugging) only as a sanity check as I construct this query. The query, when ready, will not have this condition and the results will thus be for many users.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added mysql to tag. I had left it out since I was hoping for a cross sql platform solution (but that's a secondary "nice to have").

Comment: @DougFirr - Can you add sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you need only top 1 then you can call just

select top 1

or you need make a function that returns you minimum created_contact then you just compare it with current created_contact.

I hope that will help you
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it. I used a null left join like so (on the back of other SO posts on the topic of groupwise min/max):

added this to selector:

```
e1.event_time
```

added this to joins:

```
left join bm_sets.event378 e1 on e1.eid = e.eid and e1.event_time < e.event_time
```

added this to where clause:

```
and e1.event_time is null
```